# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot Set Property 'Render' of Undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Right now I am getting these errors:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'render' of undefined**

**Cannot find element: #main**

Here is the code I have, I have tried to look for other answers but they don't seem to help. I am trying to create a simple Search Filter using VueJs Vuetify and plain JavaScript.

```js
//main.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'

Vue.use(Vuelidate)

Vue.use(VueResource)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  components: { App },
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<!-- Vue Page -->

<template>
<div id="main">
Search: <input type="text" v-model="search"/>   
<div v-bind:v-for="customer in filteredCustomers">
 <span>{{customer.name}}</span>
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#main",
  data: function(){
          return {
          search: '',
          customers: [
            { id: '1', name: 'Something', },
            { id: '2', name: 'Something else', },
            { id: '3', name: 'Something random', },
            { id: '4', name: 'Something crazy', }
          ]};
  },
  computed:
  {
      filteredCustomers:function()
      {
         var self=this;
         return this.customers.filter(function(cust){return cust.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.search.toLowerCase())>=0;});
         //return this.customers;
      }
  }
  });
</script>
```

How can I fix these errors? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is the cause, but you shouldn't be instantiating a Vue instance inside a single file component.

Instead of this:

```vue
<script>

const app = new Vue({
  ...
})

</script>
```

you should do this:

```vue
<script>

export default {
  ...
}

</script>
```

Secondly, you're trying to mount the main Vue component onto the `#main` element which doesn't exist in the DOM because it is within the template of the main component. This is a [chicken-and-egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg) problem.

You should already have a element like `<div id="main"></div>` somewhere in the DOM before you try to mount a Vue component onto it.

The `el` component option should only be used when you want the component to be mounted onto an existing element after it is instantiated. For reusable components (i.e. not the root component) you typically do not want this.

Comment: I fixed up my code and received this error:
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined".

But as for the error before it is gone now. I am going to repost this new error. I am looking for answers online but I feel as if it's a deeper issue. Thank you for your help! :)